# How can I find a path by providing only part of the path?

Tags: linux, shell, find, sh

Let's say I need to find this path `/<some_where_in_root>/find/this/path` and the only information I have is `/find/this/path`.  What would be the best means of locating the full directory?

I basically have a program that creates a directory and after the directory is created I'd like to see if a path now exist within the directory that was created.

So far I've tried `find . -type d -name "/find/this/path"` but this obviously interprets `/find/this/path` as a string.  Is there any way to use find in this situation?  Would it be best to just parse the path I have and take the `path` portion and do a search on this string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `-path` or `-ipath` with wildcards

```
find . -type d -ipath "*/find/this/path"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-path` predicate (and it's case-insensitive variant, `-ipath`) will allow you to search the entire tree for that exact text.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it is now obvious to me that I've been doing it incorrectly.  I've tried `find . -ipath "/find/this/path"`

Answer (score 2):

execute these two commands,
method1:

```
root@developer~:# updatedb

root@developer~:# locate /find/this/path
```

method2:

```
root@developer~:# tree |grep /find/this/path
```

the results will consists full path of /find/this/path

also try this 
run these from /

```
root@developer~:# cd /

root@developer~:/#updatedb
root@developer~:/#locate /find/this/path
root@developer~:/#tree |grep /find/this/path
```

Answer (score 2):

works in all flavors of *nix*:

```
applemcg.$ find / -type d -name this | grep find/this/path
```

and a little advice, when asking for help.  preface your first reference to a path of this sort with the word "directory", as in "directory path".  it took a minute to realize you were not referring to the (csh) path or PATH variable.